# Find any values from one list in another

Tags: r, unix

I have 2 lists containing gene accession codes, I am trying to search one list for any values of the other. These lists also exist as txt files. I've tried using grep in both R and unix but that doesn't seem to work, are there any other commands I can use without having to use awk in unix. Whatever I use must search for ANY of the items in list1 i.e 1111 or 2222 or 3333 or 4444, I do not require a positive match for all.

R

```
list1=c("1111","2222","3333",4444")
list2=c("0000","0001","1111","0002","0003","0004")
grep(list1,list2)
integer(0)
```

Unix

```
grep -F -f "list1.txt" "list2.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%in%` operator will tell you which (as a logical) of the values in the first list are found somewhere in the 2nd list.

The `match` function will tell you where in the second list each element of the 1st list is found with `NA` for those not in the 2nd list:

```
list1 %in% list2
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
match(list1, list2)
# [1]  3 NA NA NA
```